# Android Studioでchromeviewの使い方を教えて頂けますでしょうか？

Tags: android, android-studio, google-chrome, webview

Android4.0〜4.3でChromiumベースのWebViewを利用するために、
https://github.com/pwnall/chromeview
を使いたいと考えています。

しかし、eclipseでの使い方は書いてあるものの、
Android Studioでの使い方が書かれておらず、試行錯誤しています。

Android Studioの基本的な使い方の話しだとは思うのですが、
ご教授頂けないでしょうか？

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chromeviewのページでは開発が停止しており、代替としてCrosswalkを使うよう推奨されているようです。ソースコードを見ても非推奨のクラスやメソッドが使われていたり、例外がcatchされていなかったり、そのままビルドできないように見えます。

CrosswalkをAndroid Studioで使われる場合はこちらに記事があります。
[Embedding Crosswalk in Android Studio](http://goo.gl/zyKWcR)

Comment: ご回答頂きましてありがとうございます。
やはり、推奨されているCrosswalkを使った方が良いのですね。
早速、Crosswalkを試してみたいと思います。